# Error: Metadata version mismatch for module /mobile/node_modules/@ionic-native/core/decorators.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

Hi I have this error when try to run a command:
sudo ionic cordova run android --prod --release

Error:

```
ionic-app-script task: "build"
[16:58:40]  Error: Metadata version mismatch for module
            /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/collaborazon/WORKSPACE/mobile/node_modules/@ionic-native/core/decorators.d.ts,
            found version 4, expected 3
Error: Metadata version mismatch for module /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/collaborazon/WORKSPACE/mobile/node_modules/@ionic-native/core/decorators.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3
    at StaticSymbolResolver.getModuleMetadata (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/collaborazon/WORKSPACE/mobile/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25616:34)
    at StaticSymbolResolver._createSymbolsOf (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/collaborazon/WORKSPACE/mobile/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25404:46)
    at StaticSymbolResolver.getSymbolsOf (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/collaborazon/WORKSPACE/mobile/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:25385:14)
    at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/collaborazon/WORKSPACE/mobile/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24241:30
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at extractProgramSymbols (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/collaborazon/WORKSPACE/mobile/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24240:79)
    at AotCompiler.analyzeModulesAsync (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/collaborazon/WORKSPACE/mobile/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23796:47)
    at CodeGenerator.codegen (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/collaborazon/WORKSPACE/mobile/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/codegen.js:32:14)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.codeGen (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/collaborazon/WORKSPACE/mobile/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_api.js:73:30)
    at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/collaborazon/WORKSPACE/mobile/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:182:73
```

Here are my dependecies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.8",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.7",
    "@ionic-native/background-mode": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/badge": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/image-picker": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/push": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.4.2",
    "@ionic/cloud-angular": "^0.12.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.1.3",
    "ajv": "^5.5.2",
    "clean-css": "^4.1.11",
    "cli-update": "^3.2.5",
    "cordova": "^8.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "^6.4.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^1.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-background-mode": "^0.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.7",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "1.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic": "^2.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "~2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "~4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": "^2.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.1",
    "hoek": "^5.0.3",
    "https-proxy-agent": "^2.2.1",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.9.2",
    "ionic-native": "^2.9.0",
    "ionic-plugin-deploy": "^0.6.7",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "~2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery-touchswipe": "^1.6.15",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "npm": "^6.2.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-push": "^1.11.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "^3.6.0",
    "swift": "^0.1.8",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.0",
    "@types/node": "^10.5.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "rebuild-node-sass": "^1.1.0",
    "tunnel-agent": "^0.6.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.0"
  },
```

When I run npm outdate command I get:

```
@angular/cli                         6.2.5   6.2.5   7.0.1 
@angular/common                      4.4.7   4.4.7   7.0.0 
@angular/compiler                    4.4.7   4.4.7   7.0.0 
@angular/compiler-cli                4.4.7   4.4.7   7.0.0 
@angular/core                        4.4.7   4.4.7   7.0.0 
@angular/forms                       4.4.7   4.4.7   7.0.0 
@angular/http                        4.4.7   4.4.7   7.0.0 
@angular/platform-browser            4.4.7   4.4.7   7.0.0 
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic    4.4.7   4.4.7   7.0.0 
ajv                                  5.5.2   5.5.2   6.5.4 
cordova-android                      6.4.0   6.4.0   7.1.1 
cordova-plugin-console               1.0.5   1.0.5   1.1.0 
cordova-plugin-device                1.1.4   1.1.4   2.0.2 
cordova-plugin-ionic                 2.0.4   2.0.4   5.2.5 
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard        2.0.5   2.0.5   2.1.3 
cordova-plugin-splashscreen          4.0.3   4.0.3   5.0.2 
cordova-plugin-statusbar             2.2.1   2.2.1   2.4.2 
cordova-plugin-whitelist             1.3.1   1.3.1   1.3.3 
ionicons                             3.0.0   3.0.0   4.4.6 
phonegap-plugin-push                1.11.1  1.11.1   2.2.3 
rxjs                                5.5.12  5.5.12   6.3.3 
swift                                0.1.8   0.1.8   2.0.1 
typescript                           2.4.0   2.4.0   3.1.3
```

When I run ionic info command I get:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.2.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 6.4.0, browser 5.0.1, ios 4.5.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5, (and 15 other plugins)
```

I try to solve it few days, read related topics but I can not move forward much. Guess 1 or 2 plugins are not synchronized. Please can someone take a look?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try `npm rebuild` ?

Comment: yes, and it's rebuild successfully. But error still remain when I try 
sudo ionic cordova run android --prod --release

Comment: Could you try to upload your `package.json` file here https://update.ionic.zone/ to update all your packages, and then run `npm i` to see if you have a bad versionned package

Comment: I try https://update.ionic.zone/ but it suggest me version of packages which does not exist. Some of them are @angular/cli and  @ionic-native/transfer. Partially I solve the problem. I downgrade versions and remove plugins for notifications and file management. I need to start over to solve it.